# Accessing many-to-many relationships in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am using Core Data in my iPhone app.

I have 2 Entities: List and Item, linked by a many-to-many relationship. The relationship name in List is items and in Item is lists.

I want to get all the items from the lists selected by users.

Right now I am trying to build a predicate which look like that:

```
NSPredicate *basePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lists IN %@", listsIds];
```

listsIds is an Array of ObjectIDs

But when I run the program I get this error:

unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (lists IN {0x594ac10 })'

Any idea how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do you even need a predicate?

If the users select `List` objects then to find the related `Item` objects you just walk the `List.items` relationship.

Suppose you have an array of `List` object chosen by the user. To get an array of related `Item` objects just use:

```
NSArray *itemArray=[listArray valueForKey:@"items"];
```

Once you have one object in one side of a relationship you can find all the other objects without having to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *basePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"ALL list.objectID IN %@", listsIds];
```

Not sure if you need the `ALL` so you can also try:

```
NSPredicate *basePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"list.objectID IN %@", listsIds];
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It has make things move forward, but now for this predicate I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate (null)'
Any idea?

Comment: Ok, I have changed a bit the query: NSPredicate *basePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"ANY lists IN %@", listsIds]; It seems working fine now!